# How to make this method use ArrayList?

Tags: java

```
class Course {
    private String courseName;
    ArrayList<String> students = new ArrayList<>();
    private int numberOfStudents;

    public Course(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

    public void addStudent(String student) {
        students[numberOfStudents] = student;//<-- Line 15
        numberOfStudents++;
    }

    public ArrayList getStudents() {
        return students;
    }

    public int getNumberOfStudents() {
        return numberOfStudents;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }
}
```

Line 15 I am getting error "Array required, but ArrayList found.

I am unsure what to do here as I am new to strings and such.

Comment: We know how to count but it's always easier to tell us want is line 15.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`students` is declared as an `ArrayList`. This notation

```
students[numberOfStudents] = student;
```

only works for array types. You should use

```
students.add(student);
```

Please read the javadoc for [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

You also don't need to keep a field to hold the number of students, as

```
students.size();
```

will give you that.

Comment: you should accept his answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ArrrayList in your program:

```
public void addStudent(String student) {
     students.add(student);
   }

 public int getNumberOfStudents() {
     return students.length();
   }
```

Also then you do not require `numberOfStudents` variable